# Applying the same conditional formatting to multiple ranges (multi-range formatting rules)

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use Conditional Formatting for a really simple task:

- color cells if they have the same value as a specific another cell.

But I'm getting unexpected results when setting the range to apply!

- **Formatting rule:** format cells if `is equal to` `=G35`; (background color)

When setting the range, I made these tries, which are over 2 cells that have the exact same value as G35:

1. **Apply to Range:** `I7` → I7 is colored green, just as expected;
2. **Apply to Range:** `I7,O8` → only I7 is colored green, O8 is not. I expected both to be colored;
3. **Apply to Range:** `O8,I7` → only O8 is colored green, I7 is not. I expected both to be colored.

I would like to understand where is there error on my thought. Can someone please explain?

Here is the screenshot of the rules, as explained above:

[image: Screenshot of the Conditional Formatting Rules]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the first cell of the multiple range you're selecting and equal it to the desired one (but anchored). Imagine in the second case:

> =I7=$G$35

The conditional cell will "move" to each cell in the range, but $G$35 will remain steady

EDIT:
You can also do it with "equals to" and =$G$35 The "$" makes the row and column steady!
[image]

Comment: When using `=I7=$G$35` on the "Formatting rules">"Is equal to" field, the conditional formatting stops to work. I added a screenshot to my question so you better understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: It would be the same as saying: =if(i7=$G$35,TRUE, FALSE)

Comment: Use the formula option at the end of "Formatar celulas se.."

Comment: Is it impossible to use the "is equal to" ("é igual a") for the purpose I intend? Why?

Comment: Try it with =$G$35, it works! I'll add a screenshot too!